# ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD in MySQL (nodejs rest request)

Tags: mysql, sql, json, node.js, node-mysql

what does this error mean in mysql?
ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD –  “Field doesn’t have a default value”
I've found it listed here?
http://mysqlserverteam.com/improvements-to-strict-mode-in-mysql/
and got:

```
{
    "code": "ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD",
    "errno": 1364,
    "sqlState": "HY000",
    "index": 0
}
```

that reply in a postman request via expressjs, but this is the first table I've seem to have gotten it from.  the table has foreign keys so I set default values for the foreign keys, but I still get it.  what gives?  is the index[0] implying the name, the first json value I sent to the server?

```
{
    "name":"Cornwall Park Townhouses",
    "line1":"17 Brewster Rd.",
    "city":"Cornwall",
    "state":32,
    "zip":"12518",
    "category":2,
    "account_mgr":1,
    "active":1
}
```

heres my json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well my guess is you have a field that requires a value and has no default.
So when you insert into your table, if you don't provide a valid value for it, MySQL complains.

It'd be more help if you'd shown us your tables and maybe insert query as well, but take a look at your fields. If you find one that has no default and you're not doing anything with it, try inserting into it and passing a value for the field, if that solves the issue then you can add a default value for that field or just keep sending information to it.

If you don't want a default you could set the fields to allow null instead of a default value.

Comment: quick second question, if you're good with sql and financial systems, is the default way to timestamp something still the # of ms since like 1970 or whatever

Comment: @dkran MySQL 5.6+ has built-in timestamp functionality where the database can supply the default values, with a granularity of seconds, milliseconds, or microseconds. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html (versions before 5.5 have similar but more limited capabilities).

Answer (score 0):

this problem occured due to many reason

1. You have not enter value for the column in the API(as you have not set some default value for that column) if you set some default value you willnot have error as sql add that default value of model/migrations in that column without explicitly providing any data for that column
2. Secondly (which i face) i have make associated using alias 2 times and my alias were same while creating association so i was entering the value for column and sql was throwing this error

So the overAll conclusion of the above error is you have defined a column which has got no default value and you are adding that table in database

Answer (score -1):

I faced same problem and then I found that I had a field which is set to be AutoIncremented but I forgot to set that Auto Incremented So if you have a field that requires a value and has no default So set it Auto increment, Primary key,NotNull.